# Как правильно использовать деструктор? Он слишком рано срабатывает (C++)

Tags: c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyArray
{
    int *ptrarray;                  //массив
    int count;                      //количество элементов
    bool check_index(int index);    //Проверка на выход за пределы массива

    public:
    MyArray(int n) {
        cout<< "Тут сработал конструктор!\n";

        count = n;
        ptrarray = new int [count];
    } 

    MyArray() {
        cout<< "Тут сработал конструктор!\n";

        count =0;
        ptrarray = NULL;
    } 

    ~MyArray() {
        delete [] ptrarray;
        cout<< "Тут сработал деструктор "<<"\n";
    }

    int get_num(int index);                         //Получение элемента массива 
    void set_num(int index, int num);               //Внесение элемента в массив 
    void create_array(int n);                       //Инициализация массива через метод
    int get_count();                                //Получить значение количества элементов
    void fill_array();                              //Заполнить масив 
    void print_array();                             //Вывести масив
    void print_num();                               //Вывести определенный элемент 
    void arr_addition(MyArray obj1, MyArray obj2);  //Поэлементное сложение массивов
};

void MyArray::create_array(int n)
{
    count = n;
    ptrarray = new int [count];
}

int MyArray::get_count()
{
    return count;
}

void MyArray::fill_array()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
        cin>>ptrarray[i];
}

void MyArray::print_array()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
        cout<<ptrarray[i]<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
}

void MyArray::print_num()
{
    int index;
    cout<<"Введите индекс нужного вам элемента, index= ";
    cin>>index;
    if(check_index(index))
        cout<<"Значение выбранного вами элемента = "<<get_num(index)<<endl;
    else cout<<"ОШИБКА! Выбранный индекс выходит за пределы массива!"<<endl;
}

bool MyArray::check_index(int index)
{
    --index;
    if((index<count)&&(index>=0))
        return true;
    else return false;
}

int MyArray::get_num(int index)
{   
    --index;
    return(ptrarray[index]);
}

void MyArray::set_num(int index, int num)
{
    if(check_index(index))
        ptrarray[index] = num;
}

void MyArray::arr_addition(MyArray obj1, MyArray obj2)
{
    if(obj1.get_count() != obj2.get_count())
        cout<<"ОШИБКА! Границы индексов у массивов неодинаковые!"<<endl;
    else 
    {
        create_array(obj1.get_count());
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            ptrarray[i] = obj1.get_num(i+1) + obj2.get_num(i+1);
        }
    }
}

int _tmain()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int n;

    cout<<"Введите размер массива, n= ";
    cin>>n;

    MyArray arr1(n);        //Создаем массив 1
    MyArray arr2(n);        //Создаем массив 2
    arr1.fill_array();      //Заполняем массив 1
    arr1.print_array();     //Выводим массив 1
    arr2.fill_array();      //Заполняем массив 2
    arr2.print_array();     //Выводим массив 2

    MyArray arr3;                   //Создаем массив 3
    arr3.arr_addition(arr1, arr2);  //Заполняем массив 3 поэлементным сложением массива 1 и 2
    arr3.print_array();             //Выводим массив 3
    arr1.print_array();             //Выводим массив 1
    arr2.print_array();             //Выводим массив 2

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Насколько я знаю именно в деструкторе обычно освобождается занятая память. Что я и делаю. Но делаю что-то не так. Мне надо еще продолжать работать с массивами 1 и 2, а деструктор их уже почистил. И естественно когда я их вывожу в конце - выводится всякая ерунда. Как быть?

Comment: Вангую отсутствующий конструктор копирования. Код не читал.

Comment: ну да, два "ранних" деструктора вызываются внутри метода `arr3.arr_addition(arr1, arr2);`
я бы рекомендовал подавать параметры в этот метод по ссылке (или по указателю)
        void MyArray::arr_addition(MyArray & obj1, MyArray & obj2)
вот так вроде работает как надо

Comment: VladDб, :D Я даже не знал что это такое. 
Загуглил. Вникаю. На сколько я понял ваше предсказание верное)) Спасибо

Answer (score 3):

В функцию `void MyArray::arr_addition(MyArray obj1, MyArray obj2)` вы передаете `obj1` и `obj2` по значению. Это значит, что выполняется копирование этих объектов. Так при копировании вы копируете и указатели на созданные ранее массивы. Далее при выходе из `arr_addition` объекты `obj1` и `obj2` удаляются, то есть выполняются их деструкторы в которых и удаляются массивы.

Решение проблемы - реализовать конструктор и оператор копирования, в которых выполняется "глубокое" копирование массива.

Comment: В данном случае все таки будет проще передать объекты по ссылке

Comment: @AndrioSkur: Ну как бы да. Но вопрос ведь не в том, как сделать, чтобы не вылетало. Вопрос в том, как сделать правильно. А правильно либо имплементировать копирующий конструктор, либо запретить его. А оставлять класс с неработающим копирующим конструктором — фи.

Answer (score 1):

У тебя выполняется копирование массивов в arr_addition, после того, как время жизни копий заканчивается исходный массив преждевременно освобождается. Тебе нужно переопределить или запретить конструктор копирования, и передавать массивы по ссылке

Читай правило трёх - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D1%82%D1%80%D1%91%D1%85_(C%2B%2B_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)